# After starting Apache IoTDB, how to change admin_password?

Tags: passwords, admin, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently setting Apache IoTDB for the first time, and found that `admin_password` need to be set for the `admin` role. Since this `admin` role may need to be change to different people in my situation, I want to ask can I modify this password, `admin_password`, after IoTDB starts?

I checked the information I know, but I still do not know if I can change this parameter. I want to know if this parameter can be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first startup Apache IoTDB, the configuration you set for `admin_password` will become effective. If you want to change this password afterwards, you can use `ALTER USER <username> SET PASSWORD <password>`sql to change it in IoTDB.